# Are data type identifiers necessary when declaring a function in C?

Tags: c, function

I'm *very* new to C programming and am confused as to why functions like int main(){} include "int"? As far as I can tell, it functions fine without the data type, and leaving out the data type would make it easier to read and would be similar to languages I'm already familiar with like JS. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you omit the return type for a function in C, it is defaulted to `int` and
any calls to this function that expect anything that cannot be typecast to int will get compiler warning/error. Its good programming practise to include function return type since not all functions always return int.

> would be similar to languages I'm already familiar with like JS

No it is not similar. In languages like JS, they can return *any* data type and the rest of the code knows what to expect depending on the function and arguments. However in C, omitting return type does not mean it can return any datatype. It means it can return only int. So in your case, it would be even more confusing.